# Orchard CMS Exclude page from search

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

The title says it all, but basically I'm looking to exclude a specific page from search results (or being indexed really).  How can I accomplish this in the Orchard CMS?  I'm currently using the standard Lucene search index mechanism.

Comment: I'd create a separate "Hidden Page" content type, that I would not index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Bertrand's suggestion, just created a new content type and did not mark it to index.  Works well.